# R- Polynomial Linear model coefficients not fit predicted values of model

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to fit some models to some data and the resulting model predicts sensible values and the plots seem correct. But when extracting the coefficients and plotting the functions separately, they make no sense!. I am obviously doing something wrong, so please can someone tell me where the error is?

Data:

```
dput(distcur)
structure(list(id1 = c(1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6
), range = c(-39.898125, -21.448125, -11.07, -3.22875, 3.776484375, 
12.309609375, 22.399453125, 39.235078125), meanrat = c(20.2496, 
17.7504273504274, 12.76875, 2.475, -1.4295652173913, -3.9603305785124, 
-14.7008547008547, -19.7366666666667)), .Names = c("id1", "range", 
"meanrat"), row.names = 9:16, class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)

id = 1.6
degree = 3

press_x <- seq(min(distcur$range), max(distcur$range), length = 500)
moddist3b <- lm(meanrat ~ poly(range, degree), distcur) 
valsdist = data.frame(predict(moddist3b, data.frame(range = press_x)))

colnames(valsdist) = "pred"

valsdist$id1 = id

allvals = cbind(valsdist, press_x)

summary(moddist3b)

#test plot
pdf(paste("mod-",measure,id ))
TITLE = paste("Distance ID: ", id, "Model = line, Points = exp1")

p = ggplot(allvals, aes(x=press_x, y=pred, colour=factor(id1))) + 
             geom_line() + 
geom_point(data=distcur, aes(shape=factor(id1), x = range, y = meanrat, colour = factor(id1))) +
                ylim(-100, 100) +
                labs(title=TITLE) +
                ylab("Mean Rating (%)") +
                xlab(measure) 


print(p)
dev.off()
```

[image: Plot of model vs points]

I know the image is really bad quality, but it shows that it is correct. However the coefficients obtained from the model used to build the function look nothing like that plot:

```
summary(moddist3b)

Call:
lm(formula = meanrat ~ poly(range, degree), data = distcur)

Residuals:
       9       10       11       12       13       14       15       16 
-0.20134  0.44939  1.65996 -2.80500 -1.14594  2.98617 -0.92081 -0.02244 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            1.6770     0.8281   2.025   0.1128    
poly(range, degree)1 -37.7155     2.3423 -16.102  8.7e-05 ***
poly(range, degree)2  -2.9435     2.3423  -1.257   0.2773    
poly(range, degree)3   6.4888     2.3423   2.770   0.0503 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 2.342 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9853, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9743 
F-statistic: 89.51 on 3 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.0004019
```

Giving function y = 6.49x^3 −2.94x^2 − 37.72x + 1.68

Plotting that on google clearly shows that the function is nothing like the plot from R (from the model)

[https://www.google.com/search?q=6.49x^3+%E2%88%922.94x^2+%E2%88%92+37.72x+%2B+1.68&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=iceweasel-a&channel=fflb#client=iceweasel-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aunofficial&channel=fflb&sclient=psy-ab&q=6.49*x^3+-2.94*x^2+-+37.72*x+%2B+1.68&oq=6.49*x^3+-2.94*x^2+-+37.72*x+%2B+1.68&gs_l=serp.3...3610.3975.1.4155.2.2.0.0.0.0.107.147.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.4C6De6gdmtg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.d2k&fp=5e81885614cfda4f&biw=1440&bih=667](https://www.google.com/search?q=6.49x%5E3%20%E2%88%922.94x%5E2%20%E2%88%92%2037.72x%20%2b%201.68&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=iceweasel-a&channel=fflb#client=iceweasel-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&channel=fflb&sclient=psy-ab&q=6.49*x%5E3%20-2.94*x%5E2%20-%2037.72*x%20%2b%201.68&oq=6.49*x%5E3%20-2.94*x%5E2%20-%2037.72*x%20%2b%201.68&gs_l=serp.3...3610.3975.1.4155.2.2.0.0.0.0.107.147.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.4C6De6gdmtg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.d2k&fp=5e81885614cfda4f&biw=1440&bih=667)

Comment: Just a guess, but you probably want to enclose your independent arguments with `I(poly(range,degree))` so the `formula` is interpreted the way you want it to be.  Things like `+` and `*` have a different meaning in R-formulas.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Adding the `I` gave the exact same model, however the values predicted were almost a horizontal line, which is further away from the experiment points. The coefficients are still the same as in my question. No idea why it affected predict, but I still don't have a function for the line that is plotted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you are having has nothing to do with `ggplot`. Instead, it's how you define your linear model. As an aside, the way I figured out what was going on was to predict at 0:

```
R> (moddist3b <- lm(meanrat ~ poly(range, 3), distcur) )

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  poly(range, 3)1  poly(range, 3)2  poly(range, 3)3  
       1.68           -37.72            -2.94             6.49  

R> predict(moddist3b, data.frame(range = 0))
    1 
2.733
```

and note that the prediction was off (it should be 1.68).

Anyway, you need to fit you model using the argument `raw=TRUE`

```
(moddist3b <- lm(meanrat ~ poly(range, 3, raw=TRUE), distcur) )
predict(moddist3b, data.frame(range = 0))
```

This gives you what you expect. By default, `poly` works with orthogonal polynomials. See [this blog post](http://statistic-on-air.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/polynomial-regression-techniques.html) and the [poly](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/poly.html) help page for further details.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and get back to you. I didn't think it was ggplot2, but something with me creating the model. I have found it pretty difficult to find good resources that cover anything but the basics. Never came across `raw`. Will look into the blogs you mentioned. Cheers